# What is meant by the Number of Pages for table in Database?

Tags: database

Can anyone help me to understand the concept of pages for table in database...
thank you!

Comment: YAQQ - what don;t you understand?

Comment: I want to know what is meant by "Number of pages for a table in database"  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages... means when you are going to do any update in database you are not updating the original database which reside on the disk, but you are updating its pages.. it is one kind of copy of database, so When you are commit your transaction this page will be replaced with your original database. But you  still have to improve this answer. :)

Comment: No offence but this is a terrible answer.

Comment: Why?? Can you give answer better thn this?